# Errorbar formatting in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I was plotting some two dimensional plot in Octave my code is given below

```
A=dlmread('data.txt');
x=A(:,1);
y=A(:,2);
err=A(:,3);
errorbar(x,y,err,'or','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',5)
```

and the issue is that the markerfacecolor is not working and markersize is also not working. How could I solve this issue ?
The error shown in command window is as follows

```
error: errorbar: data argument 5 must be numeric
error: called from
__errplot__ at line 44 column 7
errorbar at line 184 column 10
rbar at line 5 column 1
```

and this code plots fine if I remove markerfacecolor and markersize. I mean it gives an output without markerfacecolor , markersize rather than showing errror in command window. Please help
The file data.txt is of this form
1.0  3.1 0.21
2.0  4.1 0.29
3.1  5.2 0.42
4.0  6.1 0.53
4.9  7.7 0.63
6.0  8.0 0.72
6.0  9.0 0.75
7.0  13.1 0.21
8.0  23.1 0.21
9.0  29.3 0.21
10.0  30.1 8.21
11.1  28.7 2.1
12.0  23.1 2.2
13.1  18.1 1.61

Comment: please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], we don't have `data.txt`

Comment: I have now added data.txt file in question

Comment: If you read [the documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/errorbar.html), you’ll notice that `errorbar` doesn’t accept name-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `markerfacecolor` and `markersize` after drawing your errorbars. i.e.

```
h = errorbar(x,y,err,'or');
set(h,'markerfacecolor','r','markersize',5);
```

**Result:**

[image]